# import local drupal site with database already exist

Tags: 7, migrations, configuration

i create a local website in my laptop and now i want to work on the project from an other laptop, after installing the module backup and migrate and active it , i download the public files settings and default database, after that in aquia dev desktop i choose import local drupal site then i choose the folder (public files downloaded) as my local code base folder and for database i choose start with Mysqldatabase dump file, at the end, after i click on the link: my local site, it shows me this :

Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Comment: Check your **settings.php** file, maybe it did not get overwritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Backup & Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) Module for importing and exporting DB's.

> Backup/Restore multiple MySQL databases and code
>   Backup of files
>   directory is built into this version
>   Add a note to backup files
>   Smart delete options make it easier to manage backup files  Backup to
>   FTP/S3/Email or NodeSquirrel.com  Drush integration  Multiple backup
>   schedules  AES encryption for backups

Comment: thank you, i have try the module to download my database and it works but when i click to my local site doesn't appear

Comment: what does that mean doesnt appear?

Comment: when i click to the url of the local site, it shows me "Internal Server Error"

Comment: check the settings.php file, may be you need to modify $base_url. And not to mention clear cache after that

Comment: http://hpics.li/c4d302e  should i modify this : # $base_url = 'http://www.example.com';  // NO trailing slash!

Comment: I think you dont need to modify that. try clear cache and check

Comment: It's work !! i delete the database and i create i new clear one then i import my old DB and i clear cache and it's work, i'm verry happy thank you so much for your help